# How to set angular cli config properties for --inline-style --inline-template for nrwl

Tags: nrwl

I created an angular app using nrwl.
Now I would like to set the properties of component, directive etc post appplication creation.

In may angular cli (no nrwl), the correct way to set the inlining of a template is

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.inlineStyle true
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.inlineTemplate true
```

The command correctly adds the following to the propertes in angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "",
...
  },
  "defaultProject": "pim",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular": {
      "component": {
        "inlineStyle": true,
        "inlineTemplate": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the generated properties have not effect - the newly generated components are still separate .html and .css files.

What is the correct way to set these configuration in nrwl?

Comment: This seems to work properly as of today. Thanks for the heads up on the proper commands!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project using following command

```
ng g c <component-name> -it -is
```

g is for generate
c is for component
while -it and -is are for inline template and inline style respectively.

Hope this helps.